# How to use css to achieve the effect circled in the picture below

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I want to know if I can use the css to realize the white line circled in the figure.

If so, can you tell me the idea, thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<h2>Top Tooltip w/ Bottom Arrow</h2>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

**.tooltip .tooltiptext::after** is the property which addes this arrow  you can play around and change its prosition